# How can I integrate Agora with Banuba Features in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, agora.io

I am trying to integrate a multi-participant video chat functionality with Banuba Face AR features. But there is no proper documentation to do that.

Can somebody please help me how can I do that?

Or is there any better Service to provide Video Filters and AR masks during live Call?

Comment: You will have to integrate Banuba using the network layer. You can have a look at this blog: https://www.agora.io/en/blog/augmented-reality-video-comes-to-life-with-banuba-and-the-agora-platform/

Answer (score 0):

6 month ago I implemented Banuba on Ionic application, I guess is the same for others mobile frameworks like flutter.
Follow those step if you want to avoid it.

First you need to learn how Writing code on specific platform and Android using Java or IOS Using Switch, that is because Banuba are implemented with native code.
I recommend read this documentation how to avoid it on flutter.
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#pigeon-example

You need create a bridge between your code on flutter and the code on Java or Switch, But the implementation is really easy because you only need follow de documentation the will send to you and follow it because the web documentation are very poor .

**Solution**

1. Read the documentation how to make a bridge between the code
   native
   https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#pigeon-example.
2. Ask for banuba to get a token becouse you need a token for
   development and production.
3. Follow de documentation, or in case of android you can use this
   example project
   https://github.com/Banuba/ve-sdk-android-integration-sample
4. FaceAr is a service of banuba by default is not available they need
   generate the token with the FaceAr active.